# this.$refs.upload.submit(); not returning response Element-UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm using element-ui and I'm uploading a file with:

```
this.$refs.upload.submit();
```

How can I get the reponse from `this.$refs.upload.submit();`?

I already tried:

```
.then(response => {
    this.success = true;
})
.catch(errors => {
    if(errors.status === 422 && this.hasError('Exists')) {
        this.Link= true;
    }
    this.success = false;
})
```

I know the `submit()` needs some sort of promise. I just don't know what to change, I just want to get the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not to familiar with element-ui but custom components almost always have events that trigger when certain functions finish.

In this case looking at the documentation:
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#upload
What you need is `on-success` or `on-error`.

So you just have to add functions to your `el-upload` component:

```
<el-upload
   :on-error="onError"
   :on-success="onSuccess">
```

And add the methods to your `methods` object in vue:

```
methods: {
      submitUpload() {
        this.$refs.upload.submit();
      },
      onError(){
        console.log("error");
      },onSuccess(){
        console.log("success");
      }
}
```

An example would be:
https://codepen.io/Freshdachs/pen/LYjWpZo

Comment: The onError onSuccess callback would not be called if you are using `submit()` method manually instead of `auto-upload`